# How to import npm packages in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I am building an Chrome Extension which uses a GraphModel loaded from tensorflowjs. However, I will need to use the tensorflowjs package to import my model using the function `tf.loadGraphModel`. Is there a way to import the packages to my chrome extension so that I can load my model? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

first of all run `npm init` so you will have `package.json` file in your folder and then install the package you need (`npm i [yourPackage]`)

then - you need to add the path to the package to `manifest.json`
for example if you are using `content_scripts` - you can add it like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://*/*"],
  "js": [
    "node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js",
    "content-script.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use webpack, which is a module bundler (it means that its main purpose is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser). If you have npm already set up, you can execute this command in your project:

```
npm install webpack
```

After you have done that you can proceed to set up your npm package. You will need to run the right npm command.

```
npm install ...
```

Continuing the setup of webpack, you will need to create a webpack.config.js file and there set the entry and the output. You can find plenty of tutorials online, but here's a quick example implementation:

webpack.config.js:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: './src/main'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        overlay: true,
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'manifest.json', to: 'manifest.json' },
            ],
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'images', to: 'images' },
            ],
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'popup.html', to: 'popup.html' },
            ],
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],


};
```

Once you've done that, in your entry file (the entry point), you can use the  tensorflowjs functions.