# Issues running auth0 with (npm) in a Chrome extension (javascript)

Tags: javascript, npm, google-chrome-extension, auth0

I've made a pure Chrome extension from scratch (no external libraries) but now need to use auth0.

Is there any way to import and implement auth0 in a chrome extension without major changes to a pure Javascript Chrome extension?

Also, how closely can I follow this quickstart to gain access to api that needs auth0?

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/01-login

Trying to use CDN gives me content security policy issues (haven't looked too hard into this yet),

auth0-chrome is deprecated,

and using node gives me a file not found error when trying to import auth0 stuff:

```js
// taken from auth0's js login quickstart
import createAuth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';
```

Comment: I'll link you to a previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71495805/18290336

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try when I'm able.

Comment: You're welcome! It's really easy to set up. If you need any help feel free to ask